# Computing Graph vertex's degrees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations

> Let $G = \langle V, E \rangle$ be a simple graph, s.t $|V| = 50$ and $deg(v) \leq 3$ for each $v \in V$.
>
>  Assume that $|\{ v \in V \space | \space deg(v) = 3 \}| = 10$.
> What does $|\{ v \in V \space | \space deg(v) = 1 \}|$ equal to?

To be honest I'm not even sure where to start. Usually I'm given $|E|$ and then I can relate it to a specific case and easily calculate it from there (i.e when $G$ is turned to be a tree). Moreover, I tried to bound $|E|$ with $ 15 < |E| < 55 $ which doesn't seem to take me anywhere too. I'd like to have some insights and what I might miss here.

Thanks

Comment: One can easily find a graph with $(v_1,v_2,v_3,|E|)=(40,0,10,35)$, and also one with $(v_1,v_2,v_3,|E|)=(0,40,10,55)$, and anything in between (with $v_1$ even), so there seems to be something missing from the question.

Comment: Sorry I struggle to understand your example. The question is actually, how many leafs exist in such a $G$

Comment: I'm saying it can be any even number from 0 to 40. You can easily find examples of each of these. I'm using $v_i$ to mean the number of vertices of degree $i$.

Comment: This is weird because that question appeared at my last exam. I assume that if there exists such a graph $G$ with the properties you mentioned then it is a counter-example, but how can you ensure the existence of $(40,0,10,35)$ for example? (.e.g why wouldnt be the set of all simple graphs which satisfy (40,0,10,35) just the empty set?)

Comment: Just build a graph with as many degree 1 vertices as possible. So surround each degree 3 vertex with three degree 1 vertices. This uses up 40 of the 50 vertices. The remaining 10 vertices can be connected in pairs to make them all degree 1 vertices. You now have a graph with 40 degree 1 vertices as required.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. So the question is wrong even if we say there are "at least" 10 vertices with degree of exactly 3, right? Since we can just use again those examples

Answer (score 1):

If you want a definitive answer look at [this famous lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

If you want to find it by yourself try thinking about how $\sum_v d(v)$, $\sum_{v\;|\;d(v) \text{is odd}}d(v)$ and other similar things are related.